# Sieve of Eratosthenes with multithreading in C/Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am currently working on the calculation of the Eratosthenes Sieve using C multithreading.

The goal is to first create a main thread that uses a split function to divide the exploration of the numbers on a number of threads.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

void *creat_thread(int *nbThreads);

void *SieveEratosthenes(int *tailleTab);

int* tab;
int sizeTab;
int nbTachesParThread=0;

int main(void)
{
  int nbThreads;
  int n;
  do{
    printf("Enter an integer > 1 :  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
  } while(n<2);


  sizeTab = n+1;
  tab = (int*)malloc(tailleTab*sizeof(int));
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<tailleTab; i++)
  {
    tab[i] = 1;
  }

  do{
    printf("Enter a number positive number of threads : ");
    scanf("%d", &nbThreads);
  } while(nbThreads<1);

  pthread_t threadPrincipal;

  if (pthread_create(&threadPrincipal, NULL, creat_thread, NULL)) {
    perror("pthread_create");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (pthread_join(threadPrincipal, NULL)) {
    perror("pthread_join");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("The Prime numbers are : \n");
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeTab; i++)
  {
    if(tab[i]==1)
    {
      printf("%d\n", (i));
    }
  }


}

void *creat_thread(int *nbThreads)
{

  int nbTachesParThread = (int) sqrt(sizeTab) / nbThreads;
  pthread_t* threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(nbThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

  int plageThreadi = nbTachesParThread;

  for(int i = 0; i < nbThreads; ++i)
    pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, SieveEratosthenes, plageThreadi);
    plageThreadi += nbTachesParThread;
}

void *SieveEratosthenes(int *plageThread)
{


  for( int i=(plageThread - nbTachesParThread); i<=plageThread; i++)
  {
    if (tab[i] == 1)
    {
      for (int j = i*i; j<sizeTab; j += i)
      {
        tab[j]=0;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I tried to implement a code but I have an error at runtime:

```
segmentation error (core dumped)
```

Comment: This `for(int i = 0; i < nbThreads; ++i)
    pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, SieveEratosthenes, plageThreadi);
    plageThreadi += nbTachesParThread;` does not what you expect. Another nice example why one shall use automated source formatting and/or curly braces, ever.

Comment: Thanks I've addded the bracket but I still have the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

On top of the issue mention in [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523757/sieve-of-eratosthenes-with-multithreading-in-c-linux/56524591#comment99632152_56523757) there is more to fix:

1st of all a PThread function needs to be of type `void *(*)(void*)`. The ones used by the code are of type `void *(*)(int*)`. Not good.

2ndly the code misses to join the work-threads, therefore the distributing thread ends after having created all workers, then it gets joined in `main()`, which then accesses the variables the workers are most likely are still working on causing undefined behaviour be doing so and then ends, ending the process. Ending the process cancels all worker-threads.

Comment: Thanks, I have some question according to the 2 points :  
1 : how can i pass arguments to the PThread function ?

2: I just need to insert a   pthread_join(threads[i], NULL) in the for loop ?

Comment: referring 2.: 1st create **all** workers, and only **then**, 2ndly join them.

Comment: referring 1.: Define thread specific variables and pass to each thread the the address of its specific, **own** variable.

Comment: Thanks so for referring 2 I need to create to for loop, one with all the create and the other with all the joins

Answer (score 0):

I followed your advice and created a structure to contain the variables that will be used by all threads.

However I noticed that sometimes it works (it displays the prime numbers well) but sometimes it doesn't work and it displays either only 0 or all the numbers from 0 to i.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>


void *creat_thread(void* arg);

void *SieveEratosthenes(void* arg);

struct param
{
  int* tab;
  int sizeTab;
  int nbTachesParThread;
  int nbThreads;
  int plageThreadi;
  int plageThreadPrecedent;
};

int main(void)
{
  struct param p;

  int n;
  do{
    printf("Enter an integer > 1 :  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
  } while(n<2);


  p.sizeTab = n+1;

  p.tab = (int*)malloc(p.sizeTab*sizeof(int));
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<p.sizeTab; i++)
  {
    p.tab[i] = 1;
  }

  do{
    printf("Enter a number positive number of threads : ");
    scanf("%d", &p.nbThreads);
  } while(p.nbThreads<1);

  pthread_t threadPrincipal;

  if (pthread_create(&threadPrincipal, NULL, (void*)creat_thread, &p)) {
    perror("pthread_create");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (pthread_join(threadPrincipal, NULL)) {
    perror("pthread_join");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("The Prime numbers are : \n");
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<p.sizeTab; i++)
  {
    if(p.tab[i]==1)
    {
      printf("%d\n", i);
    }
  }
}

void *creat_thread(void* arg)
{
  struct param *args = (void*)arg;
  args->nbTachesParThread = (int) sqrt(args->sizeTab) / args->nbThreads;
  pthread_t* threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(args->nbThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

  args->plageThreadi = args->nbTachesParThread;

  for(int i = 0; i < args->nbThreads; ++i)
    {
      pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, (void*)SieveEratosthenes, &(*args));
      args->plageThreadPrecedent = args->plageThreadi;
      args->plageThreadi += args->nbTachesParThread;
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < args->nbThreads; ++i)
      {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
      }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *SieveEratosthenes(void* arg)
{
  struct param *args = (void *)arg;
  for(int i=(args->plageThreadPrecedent); i<=args->plageThreadi; i++)
  {
    if (args->tab[i] == 1)
    {
      for (int j = i*i; j<args->sizeTab; j += i)
      {
        args->tab[j]=0;
      }
    }

  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You need a ***separate*** struct for each thread, else they are stepping on each others feet.

Answer (score 0):

In the main() function, move the calls to pthread_create() and pthread_join() outside of the if statement. These calls should be made regardless of whether or not the pthread_create() call succeeds.

In the SieveEratosthenes() function, the loop that marks composite numbers as 0 should start from i * i, not i. This is because any composite number can be written as the product of two prime numbers, and one of those prime numbers must be less than or equal to the square root of the composite number. Therefore, if a number i is composite, it must have a prime factor less than or equal to the square root of i.

In the creat_thread() function, move the call to pthread_join() inside the loop that creates the threads. This will ensure that each thread has completed before the next one is created.

In the creat_thread() function, initialize the plageThreadPrecedent variable to 2, since this is the first prime number.

Comment: Instead of writing the changes, you could just change the code yourself and present the code that the question posed with your own changes, thus making the answer more readable.

Answer (score -1):

I've modified my code so actually I have no more error code but once I have entered the 2 variables (number to calculate + number of threads), the program runs but displays nothing.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>


void *creat_thread();

void *SieveEratosthenes();

int* tab;
int sizeTab = 0;
int nbTachesParThread=0;
int nbThreads = 0;
int plageThreadi = 0;
int plageThreadPrecedent = 0;

int main(void)
{
  int n;
  do{
    printf("Enter an integer > 1 :  ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
  } while(n<2);


  sizeTab = n+1;
  tab = (int*)malloc(sizeTab*sizeof(int));
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<sizeTab; i++)
  {
    tab[i] = 1;
  }

  do{
    printf("Enter a number positive number of threads : ");
    scanf("%d", &nbThreads);
  } while(nbThreads<1);

  pthread_t threadPrincipal;

  if (pthread_create(&threadPrincipal, NULL, creat_thread, NULL)) {
    perror("pthread_create");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (pthread_join(threadPrincipal, NULL)) {
    perror("pthread_join");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("The Prime numbers are : \n");
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeTab; i++)
  {
    if(tab[i]==1)
    {
      printf("%d\n", (i));
    }
  }
}

void *creat_thread()
{

  int nbTachesParThread = (int) sqrt(sizeTab) / nbThreads;
  pthread_t* threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(nbThreads*sizeof(pthread_t));

  int plageThreadi = nbTachesParThread;

  for(int i = 0; i < nbThreads; ++i)
    {
      pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, SieveEratosthenes, NULL);
      pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
      plageThreadPrecedent = plageThreadi;
      plageThreadi += nbTachesParThread;
    }

  for(int i = 0; i < nbThreads; ++i)
      {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
      }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *SieveEratosthenes()
{
  for(int i=(plageThreadPrecedent); i<=plageThreadi; i++)
  {
    if (tab[i] == 1)
    {
      for (int j = i*i; j<sizeTab; j += i)
      {
        tab[j]=0;
      }
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Why the joining inside the create loop?

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to take it off! 
Now it works except that it displays all the numbers and not just the prime numbers (although I had tried the threadless function and it worked fine)

Comment: This second example make use of global variables. Those are accessed concurrently by the creator thread and the workers. This causes undefined behaviour if access is not protected. Protection typically is done using a mutex. But why not stick to you initial approach passing to each thread the info needed on creation?

Comment: So actually i need to put all the global variable into local variable ?

Comment: Please see my previous comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523757/sieve-of-eratosthenes-with-multithreading-in-c-linux/56525241?noredirect=1#comment99633962_56524591

Comment: I finally found the solution: I had put an int in front of global variables in my functions. 
So it works with global variables but it would be better with local variables?

Comment: It seems to work. Quoting myself: "*...  make use of global variables. Those are accessed concurrently by the creator thread and the workers. This causes undefined behaviour if access is not protected ...*" If undefined behaviour has been invoked anything might happen: From seemingly working to crash. Even using the same code just different runs.

Comment: Ah okay! So which variable should i put into argument for the Thread ? i think the Tab of integers (because i think we can only put 1 arguments per thread).

Comment: Pass to each thread what is specific to each thread. If this is more then one value, group them inside a struct and pass this strcut's address.